# Finding the subsequent of motion using a gravitational field

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, newtonian-gravity

> A constant gravitational field points along the negative z-axis. If the
>   acceleration due to gravity is $g$, the force in the z-direction experienced
>   by a particle of mass $m$ is $F = −mg$.  If the particle is released from
>   co-ordinate $z = z_0$ with the velocity $v_0$, find the subsequent motion $z = z(t)$.

Here is my work so far, not sure if I am on the right track.

Since the gravitational field $g$ around a mass $m$ is a vector field :

$g$ = $\frac{F}{m}$ = $-\frac{d^2 z}{d t^2}$ = $-GM\frac{\hat z}{z}$

Since $F = m\ddot z = -mg$

$\ddot z = GM\frac{\hat z}{z}$

to get a subsequent motion do I double integral over the right hand side $GM\frac{\hat z}{z}$?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Forget $GM$ etc.
In the question it states that there is a "constant gravitational field" and the magnitude of that filed is $g$.
So all you need to solve is the equation $\ddot z = -g$ which you probably done may times before and got the constant acceleration kinematic equations.